# During Lock Screen, Show My User, Not the Fingerprint

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, login, fingerprint

I have a Upek Eikon fingerprint reader and I am using it with Windows 7 RTM (for this question, it works the same as in Windows Vista). I was delighted to find that Windows 7 had native support and I could use it with only a driver and nothing more.

Only one thing bothers me: as a geek and nerd, I like my login screens to be tricked out. Whenever I lock my computer, however, instead of showing my user picture and a password login box like everything was normal, it shows a giant fingerprint icon and the text "Scan an enrolled finger to unlock."

Is there any way that I can change something so that it will show my picture and my name so that the fingerprint reader is not so obvious?

Comment: Saw your website - sweet work for a 12-year-old! +1

Comment: Something's not right. The website says 12, the SU profile says 19. I smell a lie here :)

Comment: @Brandon: Thats better than any website I've ever made. Great job!

Comment: @Alex: Shhhhhh. People can hear you.

Comment: @Caliban: How'd you notice that anyway? Do you regularly click through to people's profiles?

Comment: @Brandon Wang: Shhhhhh. People can hear you. :)

Comment: @caliban: LOL you just made my day.

Comment: @Brandon Wang That's what profiles are for. To discredit people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it took me a while to find out, but I got it! 
You can change the images in the following .DLL file:
c:\windows\system32\BioCredProv.dll

In the bitmap section there are 2 images in 128x128 pixels 24 bit.

Good luck!

Comment: What do you recommend using to change the images in the DLL file?

Answer (score 1):

It's annoying the hell out of me too, but nope, there's no way around it so far I think. Searched since UPEK released their beta Win 7 drivers (oh, about a few months back?) and there's still no answer...

Comment: Seriously? Oh, man this sucks.

Comment: Like many other things in techland, I guess. :) Since you are young and talented, I suggest you work your way towards employment in MS or the OS company of your choice... AND MAKE A DIFFERENCE! I'll be waiting right here to reap the rewards of your efforts towards a good UX.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
C:\Program Files\Protector Suite\rsc
```

edit the .png, rename as original file. This should fix it up.

Comment: It's indeed C:\Program Files\Protector Suite\rsc\ViLogMsg.png